# Vue update computed property only when outcome changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Consider the following simplification of a problem I have:

```js
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            i_change_alot: 0,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.i_change_alot = Math.random();
        }, 10);
    },
    computed: {
        someComputedValue() {
            this.i_change_alot;
            
            return 'a';
        }
    }
}
```

I created a property `i_change_alot` which is changed every 10 milliseconds to a random value. This means the property becomes extremely reactive and thus it will trigger the computed property.

By simply calling `this.i_change_alot` I trigger a dependency (for the purposes of example), however the *outcome* of the computed property never changes.

The end result is that the computed property `someComputedValue` updates every 10 ms and this triggers a view rerender as far as I am aware.

How can I make it so that `someComputedValue` is only rerendered when the *value/outcome* changes?

(The original problem is about showing reactive relative dates, e.g. "1 second ago", "2 seconds ago" and so on. However, after some time, this becomes `30 minutes ago`, `31 minutes ago` which means for a full minute the string representation has not changed, but it is still rerendered every 10 ms because of the dependent date property).

According to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11399 I could create a structure with a watcher but it looks so counterintuitive.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that this unchanging code, `return 'a';` is not a realistic representation of what you have going on, that sometimes the value returned by this computed property *does* change, although not necessarily when the rapidly changing value changes. What in fact *does* change the computed's output to change? And yes, why not place a watcher on that value?

Comment: The actual computed function does `return this.$filters.toRelative(this.some_timestamp, this.now);` where `this.now` is a date object that I update every second using a simple `setInterval`. The `toRelative` function creates a string representation between the 2 dates. A watcher does indeed work but I have this 4 times in 1 component which means I need 4 computed properties, 4 watchers, and 4 additional properties that the watcher changes so I can use that additional property in my view.

Comment: If you want to avoid unnecessary rendering, I would suggest to introduce another computed property `valueToRender`  that returns the `someComputedProperty` and use this  `valueToRender`  in the template. This way, the template will be rendered only when  `valueToRender` changes (i.e., the output of `someComputedProperty` has changed). But watchers are actually a good tool to achieve that behaviour as well ...

Comment: That double computed property construct doesnt work, the second computed property (which refers to the first) still takes into account the reactivity chain of the first, causing both to update the same number of ways

Comment: " it looks so counterintuitive" - it's ok because this way the values that trigger a watcher can be finely controlled. The point here is that Vue reactivity doesn't compare the value of i_change_alot to older one, it's just triggered by the fact that it was reassigned, same with the rest of reactive values. The solution is to use a watcher

Answer (score 0):

#### Why does Vue trigger the computed when the value is unchanged?

Because Vue will never know if the final result is changed or not until it makes the re-calculation. So the computed variable will be re-calculated every time its dependencies changed and there is no way to avoid it.

The common misunderstanding is Vue cache the computed variables by their value but actually, Vue cache the computed variables by their dependencies' state.

#### To avoid re-render too frequently

You can create a watcher (as you already know) or wrap your template that uses the computed value into a component.

Why wrap into another component help here?

Because Vue will convert your template to a render function. This function will be re-calculated every time its dependencies change. Sound familiar? Right, it works like a computed variable. The dependencies of a render function are all the variables that you use in the template. So, if you wrap your frequent change variable into a component, Vue will re-render that component only and avoid re-rendering your big component. It will have a big impact on your performance

Comment: Wrapping it into another component does not work or I am doing it wrong. Passing the computed property to another component only moves the issue to that other component. The reactivity continues. I think the only way to do it then is using a watcher. I'm looking into creating a Vue plugin now because I dont want to create an  explicit watcher + property for each of these computed values :)

Comment: @Flame you missed my point. Yes, wrapping it into another component will not prevent reactivity. But it will only re-render that component instead of re-render the big component every time. It is the difference.